# cmake + cpp: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, cmake

I've I'm trying to build [this "Hello World" wxWidgets example](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/overview_helloworld.html) on Linux, using the following `cmake` script:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (wxL)

find_package(wxWidgets 3.0.0 REQUIRED
    COMPONENTS base core net xml html adv qa richtext
)

file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")

add_executable(wxL ${SOURCES})
```

Building the project yields this error:

`src/wxL.cpp:3:10: fatal error: wx/wxprec.h: No such file or directory`

The file specified in the include, `wx/wxprec.h` can be found on disk at this location:

`/usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/wxprec.h`

Furthermore, another program that I have built from source includes the same file (also using cmake) and builds just fine.

So, how do I use cmake to tell the compiler that the file should be included from somewhere in the system directories?

I know I'm missing something basic, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: If the executable uses wxWidgets, won't you need to tell cmake?

Comment: Yes, but how? That is my question.

Comment: Please take some time to browse through [the CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/index.html). You need to add the include directory `/usr/include/wx-3.0` as well as set the libraries the target should link with.

Comment: It tells you on the [wxWidgets site](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_cmake.html).

Comment: Thanks @trojanfoe, `include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})` seemed to do the trick (at least now I encountered another error).

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401038/31736

Comment: You seem to have missed some parts from the link provided by @trojanfoe. Just adding the include directory isn't enough.

Comment: @dude: Which point are you referring to? Could you explain? I already have the `find_package` directive in my `CMakeLists.txt`. I just added `include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})` right after it.

Comment: The part where you need to add the libraries to link with.

Comment: Yes. I am an idiot. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you've found the package, your executable does not know anything about it.
For the executable to compile correctly, it needs to find *header* files for your package together with the *.so / .a* files. Following example should get you started:

```
include_directories(${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(wxL <add-source-files-here>)
target_link_libraries(wxL ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})    // links wxWidgets libraries to your executable
```

---

Please note that using glob is not a recommended way of adding source files to your project.

Comment: Almost correct. It's actually `target_link_libraries(wxL ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})`. Please correct this and include the `add_executable` directive (between your two lines of code) and I'll mark this answer as  accepted.

Comment: @SilviuG good thanks. Each package has its own naming conventions so it is hard to guess the correct one on the fly. I modified the asnwer tho.